# How does BeautifulSoup .hyperlinks work?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

At the moment I am analysing code from someone else and now I am figuring out what the BeautifulSoup.hyperlinks variable must have. Does anyone know documentation of this? I have not found anything on the official site. The problem is that the following code gives 'None' when I print soup.hyperlinks:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

<p class="intermezzo">this is a link: http://www.link.nl/
<a href="http://www.link.nl" title="link title" target="link target" class="link class">link label</a>
</p>

<p class="story">...</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

print soup.hyperlinks
```

I hope anybody can help me?

Comment: What makes you think `.hyperlinks` should return anything other than `None`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BeautifulSoup objects don't *have* a `.hyperlinks` attribute; there never was such a thing either.

Instead, any attribute access that BeautifulSoup doesn't recognize is turned into a call to `.find()`. `soup.hyperlinks` is interpreted as `soup.find('hyperlinks')`, searching for the first `<hyperlinks>` HTML element. Because there is no such tag, `None` is returned instead.

To find all hyperlinks in a HTML Document, just loop over all `a` tags instead, limited to those with a `href` attribute:

```
print soup.find_all('a', href=True)
```

Demo:

```
>>> soup.find_all('a', href=True)
[<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>, <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>, <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>, <a class="link class" href="http://www.link.nl" target="link target" title="link title">link label</a>]
```

You can grab all the `href` attributes too:

```
>>> [l['href'] for l in soup.find_all('a', href=True)]
[u'http://example.com/elsie', u'http://example.com/lacie', u'http://example.com/tillie', u'http://www.link.nl']
```

Comment: Now I'm further in analysing the code, next problem is it won't be found in an XML-file, however in a texteditor I do find it. But I will dig in that. Thanks!